# INSERT INTO wont work!

Tags: sql, mysql

im having some problem with this code:

```
if (count($_POST)) {

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$passwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
             VALUES ($username, $passwd)");

}

<form method="post">

<p><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p><input type="password" name="passwd" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Register me!" /></p>

</form>
```

i am connected to db
the users column ID is auto_increment

I get this when adding or die mysql_error in sql statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 2

Comment: I'm not sure if you're going to handle this later on, but storing passwords in plain text is insecure - you should hash them with a salt that is generated per user, and an application-wide salt. This safeguards your users passwords in the event that your data is exposed.

Comment: if you have plain-text security concerns go to Wikipedia and familiarize yourself with HMAC, AES, and SSL

Comment: @Hardryv: Security isn't always about INTERCEPTION. Storing them in any reversible encryption (or, worse, storing them in plaintext and only using encryption for transmission) is insecure, because that means it WILL be reversed at some point (for legitimate reasons, such as this one for comparison). If a PERSON has access to this password (rather than just a hash of it), then he potentially has access to any other site where I use that same password. There's ZERO reason to store it in reversible encryption rather than a hash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the inserted values:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
             VALUES ('$username', '$passwd')");
```

Comment: Isn't this a recipe for SQL injection?

Answer (score 2):

surround both with single quotes

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
         VALUES ('$username', '$passwd')");
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you you have a syntax error in your SQL in line 2. So something about the code

```
VALUES ($username, $passwd)
```

is wrong. Specifically you need quote characters around the parameters:

```
VALUES ('$username', '$passwd')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting ' marks around the variables in the insert:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
             VALUES ('$username', '$passwd')");
```

Answer (score 1):

what is the type of fields  username and password ?
strings ?
wrap with "

Answer (score 1):

Others gave you the right answer.

Maybe here, you can add another variable so you can see the problem next time.
And, next time, don't forget to test your query in a frontend for MySQL (MySQL Query Browser, PHPMyAdmin or so...)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
             VALUES ($username, $passwd)";

if(mysql_query($sql) === false)
{
    echo 'Error with my query : '.$sql;
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A safer way to do this would be to use a prepared statement.  Something like this:

```
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$statement->bind_param("s", $username);
$statement->bind_param("s", $passwd);
$statement->execute();
```

I used the following web page to get this snipped: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm and it has more information about using the bind_param method.  (This example is also for php5).  The concept of using prepared statements is not limited to php and is widely used in many languages for both performance and security optimizations.